# How to build a dictionary for spellchecking in Solr?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I'm trying to add spell checking to an existing Solr index.

I've added the following to the `solrconfig.xml`

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFiedlType">textSpell</str>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">my_spell</str>
    <str name="field">my_field</str>
    <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    <str nmae="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker_my_spell</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

When I try to build the index with `http://<myserver>:4103/my_index/select?&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.dictionary=cn_spell`

I don't find any evidence that any dictionary is being built, either in the response, or in the file system.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you add the spellcheck component to the "last-components" of your search handler? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add the query type to the query string. Adding `&qt=dismax` worked for me, since the spellcheck was the `last-components` of my dismax handler.

Comment: Nice. It might be useful. I will have to deal with this component very soon and since I'm always facing issues when I have to modify my solr index, I think it will be helpful.